# 'Pages' widget alternative for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, pages, widgets

I want to make a menu from a hierarchical custom post type.

There is a default WordPress widget called 'Pages' that give you list of all the pages preserving their hierarchy.

Is there a way to use this widget for custom post types?

Comment: Did you check this function [wp_list_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) ?

Comment: It will do the job! For some reason I didn't stumble upon it when googling. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per first comment, you can use [`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) like this:

```
wp_list_pages ( array ( 'post_type' => 'yourcustomposttype' ) );
```